# How to define configparser in python 3

Tags: python, configuration

I'm working on a project that will log into the site and will comment the user generated content.

I use selenium, chrome driver and python 3. All credentials user name, password and chromedriver location is configured in a separate config.ini file.

Here's the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import time
import getpass
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from configparser import ConfigParser

# Reading configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')
parameters = {}


for pairs in parser.sections():         # Parse the configuration file 
    for name, value in parser.items(pairs):
        parameters[name] = value

# Automating your browser 
chromedriver  = parameters["path"]
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

#Uncomment this block if you don't want images to load(makes the procss a little bit faster)
'''
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
'''

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
browser.get("http://www.website.com")       # website home page 
time.sleep(3)                               

# Logging into website
form = browser.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
email = form.find_element_by_name("email")
password = form.find_element_by_name("password")
email.send_keys(parameters["email_id"])
try:
    pass_word = parameters["pass_word"]
except:
    pass_word = getpass.getpass()               # If you want to enter password on terminal
password.send_keys(pass_word)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)                                   

# Fetching answers page of t6he user
answers_url = "https://www.website.com/" + parameters["username"] + "/answers"      
browser.get(answers_url)                                    

 #commenting answers one by one from top to bottom 
counter=0
while True:
    try:
        elem=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@action_click='enter']")
        counter=counter+1
        elem.click()
        time.sleep(4)
    except:
        break

print (str(counter) +" answers commented..")
```

I keep getting,

```
 config = configparser.ConfigParser()
NameError: name 'configparser' is not defined
```

Please, can anyone answer how can I define the configure.

Comment: You are getting the error because you haven't imported `configparser` you have imported `ConfigParser` _from_ `configparser`. Take a look 3 lines down from where the error is and you will see that you haven't used `configparser.Configparser()`

Comment: thanks @DavidG. should i import **configparser** or replace **config = configparser.ConfigParser()** with **config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because you haven't actually imported `configparser`. You have imported something *from* `configparser` but haven't actually imported `configparser` itself.

There are two solutions for this.

1) You can either define it by importing the module. `import configparser`

2) Or do as you have done 3 lines down from the error and use `config = ConfigParser()`

If you are using other parts of `configparser` then I would recommend to import the whole module and go with option 1. If you're only using `ConfigParser` then I would go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You Have `config = configparser.ConfigParser()` you should have `config = ConfigParser()`

You do not need to specify configparser because you are importing from it, so you just use the class you are importing which is `ConfigParser`.